# Why is this Kivy app crashing without any logical error

Tags: python, kivy

i am making an kivy database app. it was running well. recently i have added a new feature. from 2019 to 2050 in 1st january, the home page of the app, there will be a label. first, i declare the label in kv code. then give an id to the label. lastly i used if statement. if date is 1st january then the text of the label will be shown in the homepage like- " happy new year 2019" . there is no error in the logic. it runs well when i launch the app using kivy launcher. but the problem is, when i go to any page from the homepage by pressing button, and then when i come back to the homepage for the second time, then the homepage loads well and the text of the label take time to be loaded. and finally   the app crashes without any obvious reason. Where else can I look for errors?

i tried nothing as i understand nothing. i think there's no logical error. and i dont know why the app is crushing

## python code

```
class LoginPage(BoxLayout):
    mm=ObjectProperty()
    nn=ObjectProperty()
    oo=ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LoginPage,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1)
    def update(self,*args):     
        h=str(date.today())
        j=str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

        if h=="2018-12-25":
            self.ids.a.text="2019!! "
            self.ids.c.text="Have A Very Great Year. "
            self.ids.b.text="HAPPY NEW YEAR"
        elif h=="2019-12-31":
            self.ids.a.text="2020! "
            self.ids.c.text="Have A Very Great Year. "
            self.ids.b.text="HAPPY NEW YEAR"
        elif h=="2020-12-31":
            self.ids.a.text="2021! "
            self.ids.c.text="Have A Very Great Year. "
            self.ids.b.text="HAPPY NEW YEAR"

        elif h=="2021-12-31":
            self.ids.a.text="2022!! "
            self.ids.c.text="Have A Very Great Year. "
            self.ids.b.text="HAPPY NEW YEAR"
        elif h=="2022-12-31":
            self.ids.a.text="2023!! "
            self.ids.c.text="Have A Very Great Year. "
            self.ids.b.text="HAPPY NEW YEAR"
        elif h=="2023-12-31":
            self.ids.a.text="2024!! "
            self.ids.c.text="Have A Very Great Year. "
            self.ids.b.text="HAPPY NEW YEAR"
        elif h=="2024-12-31":
            self.ids.a.text="2025!! "
            self.ids.c.text="Have A Very Great Year. "
            self.ids.b.text="HAPPY NEW YEAR"
        else:
            pass
```

## kv code

```
<LoginPage>:
    mm:a
    nn:b
    oo:c
    orientation:"vertical" 

    BoxLayout: 
        orientation:"vertical"
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:1,1,1,1
            Rectangle: 
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size                       
                source:"log.png"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            height:"70dp"
            size_hint_y:None
            Label:
                id:a
                text:""
                color:1,0,0,1
                font_size:38
            Label:
                id:b
                text:""
                font_size:32
            Label:
                id:c
                text:""
                font_size:32
```

when i run the app,if the date is 1st january of any year or last day of the prevoius year,then there should be the text of the label. otherwise no text. it runs well for the first time after launching. but when i shift to another page and come back to home page the page loaded and the text label take few time to be loaded. well. now i shift to another page. then if i come back to homepage, the text label loading and finally the app crush!

Comment: you indicate that you have many pages and you try to provide a [mcve] but since that part is not then your code is not an MCVE so we can not reproduce your error and therefore it will be difficult to provide a solution. So in the end, improve your code so that it really is an MCVE including imports and the other pages.

Comment: I posted same thing in kivy users group. they replied, i should use dictionary and use the dates as key of dictionary. then it will be very easy. but i dont know how to do so. can you help me in this please

Comment: First, you must provide what I have asked for, the rules are different in the group you point to and in SO. :-)